# What's the difference between @ResponseBody and HttpServletResponce

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets

When I tried to user Micro Message Public Platform, the weChat server will invoke one of my API and I need to return a token to validate my identity. However，when I return the token directly like this, the weChat server alerts that validation is error.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/userFollow", method= RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String weChatToken(HttpServletRequest request,String signature,String timestamp,String nonce,String echostr,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    String result=weChatService.checkSignature(signature,timestamp,nonce,echostr);
    return result;
}
```

Then I changed my code as below. This time, the validation is correct.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/userFollow", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String weChatToken(HttpServletRequest request,String signature,String timestamp,String nonce,String echostr,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        String result=weChatService.checkSignature(signature,timestamp,nonce,echostr);
        PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
        pw.write(result);
        pw.flush();
        return null;
    }
```

I Googled and got that when using `@Responsebody`, Spring write messages to the body of response.
So what's the difference between them? Why the first way is Wrong?

Comment: responseBody is only the body of the response, while `HttpServletResponce` contains the whole response, eg headers, cookies, body etc..

Comment: Is the posted code correct? You have @ResponseBody on both methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An HTTP response consists of a status code, some headers, and a body. Using @ResponseBody means your method gives the content of the body, and nothing else. Using HttpServletResponse enables your method to set all aspects of the response, but is a little inconvenient to use.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ResponseBody for returning some data structure. Since you need "only" String, you should change the return type of your method to void from String and remove ResponseBody annotation.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/userFollow", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public void weChatToken(HttpServletRequest request,String signature,String timestamp,String nonce,String echostr,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    String result=weChatService.checkSignature(signature,timestamp,nonce,echostr);
    PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
    pw.write(result);
    pw.flush();
}
```